# “The Install OS X Mavericks application can’t be used from this disk” OS X 10.9 Installation Error

Tags: macos, install, dvd

[image]

I am trying to install OS X Mavericks on my Mid-2011 iMac. Before you tell me to upgrade, Mavericks is my favorite version and anything after it runs like crap.

Please help me fix this!

Comment: What is your current setup? What is installed on the iMac now, and where is the installer application (it's complaining about the disk it's on -- what is that disk and how is it formatted)?

Comment: This is a Mid-2011 iMac 21.5” “Core i5” model running 10.8 Mountain Lion (my iMac was made in October 2012). I have a Seagate SATA HDD and the i5-2400S. I am installing to my hard disk, and I want to do a clean install. I am trying to use a DVD to install Mavericks. USB drives are bad luck for me, they never work. I’ve had success installing 10.8 off of a dvd, but Mavericks isn’t working for some odd reason.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: I have successfully been able to fix my problem. I started off by making a Mavericks USB installer, then I made a disk image from the drive. My mistake was making a .cdr file and burning it. I tried again by making a .dmg file instead. I now have Mavericks installed. It also took significantly quicker to get into the recovery menu.